# Ubuntu 12.04 Window installer edition?

Tags: installation, 12.04, windows, windows-7, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I download the Windows installer from the Ubuntu website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146718/why-cant-i-download-the-windows-installer-from-the-ubuntu-website)

I am using Windows 7. Now, I wish to install Ubuntu 12.04 with the Windows installer. But I cannot install it. Please guide me. How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 with the Windows installer on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

To install Ubuntu with the Wubi installer (i.e., with the installer than runs in Windows and puts Ubuntu inside the partition that already exists for your Windows system), follow the [official instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) (which are a click away from the download page).

If you encounter a problem while following these (or any other) instructions, it is best to post a question that includes a link to the instructions you're using, describes in detail what you did, and describes in detail whatever went wrong (including the full and exact text of any error messages).

Answer (score -4):

Its very easy.  Read this guide here - http://ubuntu-helpcenter.blogspot.in/2012/03/p-002.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.