# Why can't I download the Windows installer (Wubi) from the Ubuntu website?

Tags: system-installation, wubi

When I click on, "start download" in the link below, it doesn't begin.

[Windows Ubuntu Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

Instead it directs me to the page where I can download Ubuntu Desktop, here:

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

What should I do?

Comment: It maybe a bug.  I went ahead and filed a bug report.  I will let you know when it gets fixed.

Comment: At this moment there seems to be a problem with it, If your Using Ubuntu 12.04 Download it [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe).If other version please specify. For instruction refer [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

Comment: @Mitch Excellent, thank you for your work reporting this bug. [Here's the bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1009697) People who have confirmed that this bug occurs for them can use the green "This bug affects..." link to indicate this.

Comment: It's been fixed now (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1009247)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with Ubuntu's website.

You can download the latest Windows Ubuntu Installer here: [At CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Wubi/3000-2094_4-10701841.html) (Hit the green button in the top left, under the word "Wubi")

This is a trustworthy website and I would not expect any issues from downloading from here but I cannot take any responsibilities for any issues you have with this website.

Once you have downloaded the tool you can proceed as normal, if you require any further help with the Windows Ubuntu Installer let me know.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Or get it from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe

Answer (score 1):

No, you're right - I tried and have the same issue as you're seeing.

Never mind, suggest downloading from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32) and follow the instructions to either create a bootable USB stick [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or to burn a CD [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows). Then simply boot from the USB or CD, and when the Ubuntu desktop loads, play around with it. Don't worry, no changes have been made to your computer at this point and you can go back to Windows.

Test your wifi, internet access, speakers etc. If you like Ubuntu, then (and only then) click the Install link on the Ubuntu desktop. Before doing so, **please remove the Ubuntu CD or USB stick, boot into Windows and back up all your important files**. Back them up onto another USB stick or removable media, not the one you will use to boot Ubuntu with.

When you reboot with the Ubuntu install media loaded, the installer will give you the choice to install alongside Windows or overwrite Windows. Suggest installing alongside Windows until you've had enough time to see if Ubuntu is for you. This way you will be able to boot Windows or Ubuntu as you choose - the boot menu will give you both options.

Answer (score 1):

This link has been acting flaky for me too in the last day or so.

Try this [direct link](http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-releases/precise/wubi.exe) from Ubuntu's official New Zealand mirror (which is actually in California, USA).

Or [browse to the release directory yourself](http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-releases/precise/) and download `wubi.exe` from the very bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mount the downloaded ISO on any virtual drive.

"Explore" it.

Copy the file Wubi.exe to your desktop.

Run it there keeping the iso mounted. You will find the "Install inside windows" option.

The wubi.exe present in the Iso is itself the windows installer, it just doesn't behave like that when you execute it from the CD. Take it out of the cd and run it, you will find what you are looking for :) Otherwise you can also download the Wubi separately from the Ubuntu site, named as windows installer.