# Am I missing the Windows installer? It keeps taking me to the same page and I keep running around in circles

Tags: installation, windows, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I download the Windows installer from the Ubuntu website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146718/why-cant-i-download-the-windows-installer-from-the-ubuntu-website)

Ok so going here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows takes you to here:  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer which takes you to here:  http://www.ubuntu.com/download which takes you to here:  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer all while clicking on what I think should begin the installer download... am I missing something????