# Redirected to Ubuntu downloads page when clicking the wubi download button

Tags: wubi, downloads, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I download the Windows installer (Wubi) from the Ubuntu website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146718/why-cant-i-download-the-windows-installer-wubi-from-the-ubuntu-website)
>   [Am I missing the Windows installer? It keeps taking me to the same page and I keep running around in circles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146926/am-i-missing-the-windows-installer-it-keeps-taking-me-to-the-same-page-and-i-ke)

Aloha. When I try to download Wubi and hit download now, it wont download. It just redirects me to the page before, the Ubuntu downloads page, Is this an error on the site, or a bug on my comp? Thanks